# Kronecker Product Expression Related to Matrix Differential

Tags: kronecker-product

The equivalence of the below expressions is well documented (see, e.g., Brewer (1978). Kronecker Products and Matrix Calculus In System Theory, *IEEE Trans on Circuits and Systems,* **CAS-25**(9) 772:781, Sep 1978): for $\underline{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times q}$ and $\underline{D} \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times s}$,
$$
(\underline{I}_s \otimes \underline{A})\, \text{vec}[\underline{D}] 
    = (\underline{D}^T \otimes \underline{I}_p)\, \text{vec}[\underline{A}] 
    = (\underline{D}^T \otimes \underline{A})\, \text{vec}[\underline{I}_q]
    = \text{vec}[\underline{A}\, \underline{D}].
$$
These require that $\underline{A}$ and $\underline{D}$ be compatible matrices for multiplication. What if they are not compatible? Are there equivalences that are analogous to the above in such a case?

I am interested in this because of the following equation that I have encountered:
$$
(\underline{I}_N \otimes \underline{x}^T)\, 
\frac{\partial \underline{B}^T}{\partial \underline{x}},
$$
where $\underline{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times 1}$ and $\underline{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$, meaning that $(\underline{I}_N \otimes \underline{x}^T) \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N^2}$ and $\partial \underline{B}^T/\partial \underline{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{N^2 \times N}$. Note that, $\underline{x}^T$ and $\partial \underline{B}^T/\partial \underline{x}$ are not compatible.

Any advice/suggestion/comment is most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If $B$ is a row vector $B\in{\mathbb R}^{1\times N^2}$ then the equation is compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to all who responded to this question. I have now been able to establish the following identities:

Given $\underline{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times 1}$ and $\underline{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$,
$$
  \frac{\partial \underline{A}}{\partial \underline{x}^T}
  \centerdot
  [\underline{I}_N \otimes \underline{x}]
    = \left(
        \underline{x}^T \otimes \underline{I}_N
      \right)
      \frac{\partial [\text{vec}[\underline{A}]]}{\partial \underline{x}^T}
    = [\underline{I}_N \otimes \underline{x}^T]
      \centerdot
      \frac{\partial [\text{vec}[\underline{A}^T]]}{\partial \underline{x}^T},
$$
where $\text{vec}[\cdot]$ denotes stacking the columns on top of each other. Note that, if you transpose these identities, we get identities for
$$
  [\underline{I}_N \otimes \underline{x}^T]
  \centerdot
  \frac{\partial \underline{A}^T}{\partial \underline{x}},
$$
which is the expression I mentioned in my initial post.

If you have come across these identities, please let me know the location where they appear; or, if you feel there is something wrong in these identities, again, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Non-compatible equalities are not allowed. Therefore, equalities 1 and 2 hold and 3 do not. You must add a compatibility matrix by substution of identity matrix by some rectangular matrix. Take a look at Theorem 1 [here](https://www.ime.unicamp.br/%7Ecnaber/Kronecker.pdf).

$$\mbox{vec}(AXB) = (B^\intercal \otimes A) \mbox{vec}(X)$$

I will call $\frac{\partial B}{\partial x}$ as matrix $B_x$ and each column of $B_x^\intercal$ as column vector $c_i$. Therefore, we use the above identity for expression $(I_n \otimes x^\intercal) \, c_i$. The vector $c_i$ has dimension $n^2 \times 1$, thus vec$(c_i)$ emerges an square matrix $C_i$. Finally, the desired result $(I_n \otimes x^\intercal) \, B_x$ corresponds to the column composition of column vectors $\mbox{vec}(x^\intercal C_i)$, for index $i$ from 1 to $n$. $\blacksquare$.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. by "equality 3", I am assuming you meant $(\underline{D}^T \otimes \underline{A})\, \text{vec}[\underline{I}_q]$ . This is a perfectly valid expression because $(\underline{D}^T \otimes \underline{A}) \in \mathbb{R}^{ps \times q^2}$ and $\text{vec}[\underline{I}_q] \in \mathbb{R}^{q^2 \times 1}$.

Comment: An equality is given by left and right hand sides. By "equality 3" I mean the equality symbol and right hand side $vec(\cdot)$

Comment: I added some additional material that will satisfy your need.

Comment: So, you mean $\text{vec}[\underline{A}\, \underline{D}]$, right? Again, this is a perfectly valid expression because $\underline{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times q}$ and $\underline{D} \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times s}$, meaning that they are compatible for multiplication. Of course, $\text{vec}[\underline{A}\, \underline{D}] \in \mathbb{R}^{ps \times 1}$. These expressions are proven in Brewer's reference that I mention in my original post. My inquiry is regarding whether similar expressions can be derived for the incompatible case. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, my clarification regards about non-compatible multiplication as I mention at the first word.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. You had posted your last response while I was typing my response. Yes, this expression for $\text{vec}[\underline{A}\, \underline{X}\, \underline{B}]$ is also available in Brewer's paper. But, in my particular situation, this cannot be directly applied because the right-hand side may not even be a column vector (whereas $\text{vec}[\underline{A}\, \underline{X}\, \underline{B}]$ is guaranteed to be).

Comment: May you provide the motivation for your example here?

Comment: Do my changes suffice now?

Comment: Thanks, but unless I am mistaken, this would not work. If $B_x^T \in \mathbb{R}^{N^2 \times N^2}$, then each of its columns $\underline{c}_i,\, i \in \{1, \ldots, N^2\}$, has size $\underline{c}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{N^2 \times 1}$. But then we cannot use the equation  $(\underline{I}_N \otimes \underline{x}^T)\, \underline{c}_i = \text{vec}[\underline{x}^T \underline{c}_i]$ because $\underline{x}^T \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times N}$ and $\underline{c}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{N^2 \times 1}$ are not compatible.

Comment: Youself wrote, apart from my own corrections, $\frac{\partial B^\intercal}{\partial x} \in  \mathbb{V}(\mathbb{R}^{n^2 \times n}$), for $\mathbb{V}(\cdot)$ the function space of smooth entries under real values, which is equal to $B_x^\intercal$.

Comment: Oh yes, I initially stated that $\partial \underline{B}^T/\partial \underline{x}$ is of size $N^2 \times N$, and in my last post I have used $N^2 \times N^2$. Sorry about that. However, irrespective of the number of columns, it has $N^2$ rows whereas $\underline{x}$ has only $N$ elements. So, one cannot form $\underline{x}^T \underline{c}_i$. In any case, thank you so much for your efforts.

Comment: It was my pleasure.